# Struggle with EJS and scope of -not so- "local" variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, ejs

I'm wondering how I should write my node.js application, using EJS template.
I'm actually looking for a proper way to define local variables with default values in a partial/template.

I'll exlain quickly of it works now:

When I call a template, like this:

```
<%- partial(__view.partialPath('tagPopover'), {
    title_popover: sentence.nickname,
    content_tag: '#' + sentence.nickname,
    icon_popover: 'http://placehold.it/64x64'
}) %>
```

I manage the default values this way, in the `_tagPopover.ejs` partial:

```
title_popover = typeof title_popover != 'undefined' ? title_popover : ''
classes_tag = typeof classes_tag != 'undefined' ? classes_tag : 'tags'
icon_popover = typeof icon_popover != 'undefined' ? icon_popover : false
content_tag = typeof content_tag != 'undefined' ? content_tag : ''
```

I don't use the `var` keyword, because it doesn't work at all, for instance, if I do:

```
var title_popover = typeof title_popover != 'undefined' ? title_popover : ''
```

Then EJS will interprate the `var title_popover` and create a local variable **before to read** the actual value of the variable `title_popover`. So I'll end up with a `null`, even if I actually sent a parameter...

When I discovered that, I decided to not use the `var` keyword... But I just recently discovered that all the variables that I create this way are actually `global`! Meaning that it's a really bad solution because I may likely end up rewriting global variables by loading a view!

I believe this will be a struggle later and I don't want my views to set/reset global variables by default (who would?!)

Do you have any solution for this? I thought about several already but I don't like any:

1. Use the `var` keyword but also use a *before pattern* for local variable to avoid resetting parameters: `var l_title_popover = typeof title_popover != 'undefined' ? title_popover : ''`. This looks bad and confusing as hell.
2. Use a namespace like `view.title_popover = typeof title_popover != 'undefined' ? title_popover : ''`. I want my variables to be locals, not globals, if I do so I will have something global that will exist in memory all the time.

How would you deal with that? I'm quite curious, maybe there is some EJS way to handle that or a helper, I don't know.

Comment: can you please mark as accepted if this answers your question?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Yes, `var` does always create local variables, but they would be initialised with `undefined`. Not sure what you mean by "read the actual value", but inside the `with` they will definitely have the value that was passed by the object. And there's nothing where a `null` would come from. And no, even if you omit `var`, it will not create global variables as long as you use the same variable names that you did pass as object properties (`classes_tag` is missing in your example, though).

Comment: I don't send the `classes_tag` because I want to use the default one. But if I do that way then it creates a global variable. About the *before to read*, it means that somehow EJS initialize a new variable before to read the value of the variable, like that: `var icon_popover = typeof icon_popover != 'undefined' ? icon_popover : false`, it creates a new local `icon_popover`, **before** to read the `icon_popover` parameter I sent, then it tries to read it, but it's `null`, of course. I don't get what you mean by "but inside the `with`" though.

Comment: I actually think the filters approach is the way to go, as it's the clearest to read and understand.  Other templating libraries take similar approaches (see [Liquid filters/tags](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid) with Ruby).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a concept of [filters](https://github.com/tj/ejs#filters) in ejs.  Also see [adding-filters](https://github.com/tj/ejs#adding-filters).

Basically I think you're looking for something similar to this..  Code below will set title_popover if exists in the res.locals, otherwise it sets to 'some default value'

```
<%=: locals | get:'title_popover','some default value' %>  

ejs.filters.get = function(obj, prop, default) {
  return obj[prop] === undefined ? default : obj[prop];
};
```

I believe this is the easiest way to do it in ejs, but there might be some other methods.  Looks like [this actually being discussed on a github ticket](https://github.com/tj/ejs/issues/8) :)

EDIT - [This blog post](http://justjs.com/posts/page-templates-with-ejs-finally-we-can-have-nice-things) seems to give some alternatives using the underscore library.  Looks like they're wrapping the template in a layout somehow (I haven't fully grokked the article but it seems to make sense on the surface).

I've only used the above way however.

Comment: Note that I haven't had time to test your solution but awarded the bounty anyway since I took a quick look and it seemed okay. I'll test ASAP.

Comment: The current EJS module has removed filters. They have nothing to do with embedded JS, and are easy to replicate with your own code.

Answer (score 0):

EJS is not a good template, as is to be expected because it's very old and inactive. That said, the templating engines for JS are not all that well-featured when it comes to passing variables around. I am using Sails framework and what I do is simply pass the variables to the view in either my route settings (if they are hardcoded) or in my Controllers, if they are dynamic.

It is also possible to provide standard route settings to `res.locals` via policy.

For example I have the following settings in my sails routes:

```
  'GET /':{
    controller: 'IndexController.js',
    action: 'displayIndexPage',
    title: 'Main page',
  },
  'GET /flowchart': {
    controller: 'FlowchartController.js',
    action: 'displayFlowchart',
    title: 'Flowchart'
  }, //...
```

Then I have a policy `viewToLocals.js` with the following code:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.view = req.options.title;
  return next();
};
```

This, btw, will not override any data I pass to the view from controller or any other file. What I could do if I had your problem would be something like this:

```
//setPageParamsPolicy.js
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.popovers = {
  title: ('undefined') ? res.get('body').username : 'Default title', //or wherever you fetch data from
  icon : ('undefined') ? res.get('body').avatar : 'www.site.com/defaultAvatar.jpg'
}
  return next();
};
```

Sails is built on Express, so maybe this information will be useful. Note however, that sails policies apply to controller actions, which means if you define a simple route to view, it won't apply - you have to route it to a particular controller instead. However you can put this object into the routes themseleves:

```
//routes.js
'GET /userpanel': {
    view: 'userpanel',
    locals = {
          popover: {
              title: ('undefined') ? res.get('body').username : 'Default title', //or wherever you fetch data from
              icon : ('undefined') ? res.get('body').avatar : 'www.site.com/defaultAvatar.jpg'
         }
    }
}
```

I have also wondered about this and came to the conclusion that there is no easy way to do this. But to me Sails provides a relatively straightforward solution that is also relatively foolproof.

Comment: I also use sails.js with all that you explained there, but that's not the point. I can't use `res.locals` from the controller since I'm using templates which are using templates, the view creates its own `popover`, the controller doesn't create `popover[]` for all view that may need them. But I agree, EJS isn't a good templating engine at all. So bad it comes with Sails by default.

Answer (score 0):

EJS is an excellent templating language if you like using plain JS for things. The project is currently quite active.

The EJS module (now v2) on NPM is actively maintained here: https://github.com/mde/ejs. (The old v1 repo is no longer maintained.)

Landing site is here: http://ejs.co

Default values for data shouldn't be set in a template. Templates should only be used for rendering. A better approach would be to preprocess your data before passing it in:

```
var defaultVals = {
  foo: 'FOO',
  bar: 'BAR'
};
// Mix in left to right: https://gist.github.com/mde/81b131ff6810ed7c4e0e
var dataObj = mixin({}, defaultVals, {bar: 'NOT BAR'});
// Outputs "FOO, NOT BAR"
ejs.render('<%= [foo, bar].join(", "); %>', dataObj);
```

Incidentally, filters were removed from EJS in v2. They were a nonstandard feature that had nothing to do with embedded JavaScript, and are easy to replicate using your own code.

Comment: Yes, default data should be managed by the templates, since they are *strongly linked to them*. For instance I usually have a variable for the container id or name or css classes, these "data" are 100% linked to that specific template and dealing with default values should be made within templates, not coming from some controller since a same template can be used by many other templates.

Comment: And no, to my point of view, EJS *is not* a good templating language, each version/sub-version remove features, all the time, it was badly designed at the start and it's quite hard to find good documentation and help since it changes quite often, which leads to use of third party modules, which are not always maintained, which complicates **a lot** the use of that templating language.

Answer (score 0):

I defined default variables in ejs like this:

```
<%  var username, password%>
<script>
    var username = "<%= username %>",password = "<%= password %>" %>
</script>
```